# Scanner doesnt want to read Cyrillic content

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I used scanner class a lot of time. But in this case a circle while(scanner..hasNext()) return anything. The path of file is correct.
What could be the reason? i attached code and files content.

```
 public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        File file = new File("D:/t1.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\s");

        while (sc.hasNext()){
            String ss = sc.next();
            System.out.println(ss);
        }
       sc.close();
    }
}
```

file t1.txt

```
Киев Нью-Йорк Амстердам Вена Мельбурн
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably unrelated with your problem, but you should always specify the [charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thanks you,it helped me a lot i throught problem was in my code or in idea.

Answer (score 1):

thanks. I have solved this problem using other charset

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    File file = new File("D:/t1.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file,"windows-1251");
    sc.useDelimiter("\\s");

    while (sc.hasNext()){
        String ss = sc.next();
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
   sc.close();
}
```

}